# Autoclose dropdown menu problem with ng-select

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu, that closes automatically when the user click outside of it. In this menu I added a [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) component, but when I click on one of the options, the menu will close, because the dropdown panel of the ng-select is not inside the DOM when it is closed, is there any way to achieve what I want? The dropdown menu to not close when the user select a ng-option?
Here there is an example of the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8m1ta5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Here is the code that I use to keep track of the click of the user:

```
  @ViewChild('father', {static: false}) father;
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public onClick(targetElement) {
    const clickedInside = this.father.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!clickedInside) {
      this.dropdown = false;
    }
  }
```

`#father` identify the container of the dropdown menu.

Comment: Please do not add answers in the question post

Answer (score 5):

The Attribute `[closeOnSelect]="false"` should do the work. You will have to add it to the `<ng-select>` tag

So, from the stackblitz the code will become:

```
<ng-select placeholder="Status" [closeOnSelect]="false">
        <ng-option [value]="'0'">Option 1</ng-option>
        <ng-option [value]="'1'">Option 2</ng-option>
        <ng-option [value]="'2'">Option 3</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Here you can find the documentation https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

Comment: I don't want the ng-select drop down not to close when an item is selected. I don't want the whole drop down menu to close when an item is selected

Comment: But the the ng-select dropdown should be closed after selecting or it would still be opened?

Comment: It can close, as normal.

Comment: I think you will bind an ngModel or a formControl, so just add to the ngIf the condition that this variable is not null. I didn't understand if you want that clicking outside if the option is selected should make the ng-select  hidden, let me know

Answer (score 0):

binding the `isOpen` property of `ng-select` to your components `dropdown` flag should do the trick:

```
<ng-select placeholder="Status" [isOpen]="dropdown">
    <ng-option [value]="'0'">Option 1</ng-option>
    <ng-option [value]="'1'">Option 2</ng-option>
    <ng-option [value]="'2'">Option 3</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  dropdown = false;

  @ViewChild('father', {static: false}) father;
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(e) {
    const clickedInside = this.father.nativeElement.contains(e.target);
    if (!clickedInside) {
      this.dropdown = false;
    }else{
      this.dropdown=true;
    }
  }
}
```

have a look at https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#inputs

I have altered your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8m1ta5)

Comment: The stackblitz does not seems to be updated, but I tried to apply your fix but it does not work as I want. With your update when I open the dropdown menu, the ng-select will be already open, and when I select an option from it, it will not close automatically. What I want is: Open the drop down, click anywhere in the dropdown menu and the menu will not close, click outside of it then it closes. If I select an option from ng-select the ng-select will close as normal but the menu does not close.